# LINQ where clause- compare collection of strings

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a variable number of "filters" to apply to an entity collection, and these filters are stored in a List. Right now, I'm doing the following:

```
    IQueryable<Items> items = SharedContext.Context.Items.GetAll();
    //This list is dynamic, but shown static here for simplicity
    IEnumerable<Items> filterList = new List<string>(){"new", "old", "current"};
    IEnumerable<Item> items_temp = new List<Item>();
    foreach (string type in filterList)
    {
        var temp = items.Where(i => i.Type.ToLower().Trim() == type.ToLower().Trim());
        items_temp = items_temp.Union(temp);
    }
    items = items_temp.AsQueryable();
```

Unfortunately, this causes a huge performance issue. I know somebody out there has a better solution... What do you guys think?

**EDIT**
Running my application with the code above takes around 30 seconds to execute, but if do the following:

```
    items.Where(item => item.Type.ToLower().Trim() == "new" ||
                        item.Type.ToLower().Trim() == "old" ||
                        item.Type.ToLower().Trim() == "current");
```

my application executes in about 4 seconds. Can anyone think of a solution that can match this performance or at least fill me in on why the results are so drastically different? FYI, I'm binding my data to a grid with multiple grids nested inside... a small improvement can go a long way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is this:

```
var items = SharedContext.Context.Items.GetAll();
IEnumerable<string> filterList = new List<string>(){"new", "old", "current"};
var filteredItems = items.Where(i => filterList.Contains(i.Type.ToLower()));
```

If you're having issues with this, you might want to try using an array instead:

```
string[] filterList = new string[] {"new", "old", "current"};
var filteredItems = items.Where(i => filterList.Contains(i.Type.ToLower()));
```

---

**Update:** Here's another strategy which generates a filter expression dynamically:

```
var filterList = new[] { "new", "old", "current" };
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item));
var left = 
    Expression.Call(
        Expression.Call(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(param, "Type"),
            typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes)),
        typeof(string).GetMethod("Trim", Type.EmptyTypes));
var filterExpr = (Expression<Func<Item, bool>>)Expression.Lambda(
    filterList
        .Select(f => Expression.Equal(left, Expression.Constant(f)))
        .Aggregate((l, r) => Expression.OrElse(l, r)), 
    param);
var filteredItems = items.Where(filterExpr);
```

Comment: +1 for offering a cleaner solution. Although, it didn't have much of an effect on execution time. See my edit.

Comment: @MrJones It should help quite a bit if you execute the `Where` on the `IQueryable` directly. That should translate to an `IN` clause in SQL. You could also try to do something using `Expressions`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks for the update. What do you mean by execute the `Where` on the `IQueryable` directly? Aren't I doing that already by doing items.Where(...)?

Comment: @MrJones Yes, on closer inspection, you're right. The problem is actually the `Union`, not the `Where`. You are calling `Queryable.Where`, but then you use `Enumerable.Union` which forces it to query the database, and then it does the actual union in memory.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a join to filter the items:

```
IEnumerable<Items> filterList = new List<string>(){"new", "old", "current"};          
IQueryable<Items> items = SharedContext.Context.Items.GetAll();

var filteredItems = from i items
                    join f in filterList 
                      on i.Type.ToLower().Trim() equals t.ToLower().Trim()
                    select i;
```

Comment: Interesting approach. This was indeed faster. It brought the execution time down to around 20 seconds, but still not quite there.